# How Guava's Multimaps class's index() function works internally?

Tags: java, collections, guava

I am trying to understand [Multimaps](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html) class's [index](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index-java.util.Iterator-com.google.common.base.Function-) function. If I want to use it like a HashMap then I can just put multiple values against a key and retrieve them with the same key.

But if I want to group the data according to some criteria then Multimaps implementation like [this](https://javahowtodoit.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/guava-function-example-how-to-use-function-with-multimaps-index/) is used.

Now I have a doubt in below declaration of index function.

```
public static <K,V> ImmutableListMultimap<K,V> index(Iterator<V> values, Function<? super V,K> keyFunction)
```

If ImmutableListMultimap is to be returned with `<K,V>` then why does Function have the type declaration of `<? super V,K>`, which is exactly opposite?

Also how does the anonymous inner class of type Function works as shown in [this](https://javahowtodoit.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/guava-function-example-how-to-use-function-with-multimaps-index/) example? I am not able to understand who calls the apply method defined inside the anonymous inner class Function?

Comment: Do you know you can click through the JavaDoc to [the actual code](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#line.1542) to see for yourself?

Comment: @PetrJaneček I did take a look but found it complex enough to understand.

Comment: By the looks of it, Guava is sorting (or indexing) by the value instead of the key, which is why they pass in the value to the `keyFunction` which will return it's respective key. Basically it takes in a list of values and produces a key for each value.

Comment: As the javadoc states: _The key used to store that value in the multimap will be the result of calling the function on that value_, meaning the for each value obtained from the input iterator it calls `K key = keyFunction.apply(value);` and then stores the value in the result-Multimap with `multimap.put(key, value);`

Comment: As to why the function has the type declaration `Function<? super V,K> keyFunction`: the function has to take a value (V)  as parameter and needs to return the key (K).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If ImmutableListMultimap is to be returned with <K,V> then why does Function have the type declaration of <? super V,K>, which is exactly opposite?

A Multimap has the two type parameters `K` for the keys and `V` for the values. The `index` method has the parameters `Iterator<V> values` (obviously for the values) and `Function<? super V,K> keyFunction` (for generating a key for a value).

That means that the `keyFunction` has to accept a value (of type `V` or one of its supertypes, since you can pass any value of type `V` to a method accepting a supertype of `V`) and it has to return the key (of type `K`) for that value. This leads to the type `Function<? super V,K>`.

> Also how does the anonymous inner class of type Function works as shown in [this](https://javahowtodoit.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/guava-function-example-how-to-use-function-with-multimaps-index/) example? I am not able to understand who calls the apply method defined inside the anonymous inner class Function?

If you look at the implementation of the `index` method (https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v23.0/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.java#L1630), you will see that line 1637 that the `index` method calls `keyFunction.apply(value)`